# how to stop creating temporary files

Tags: sed

when i use `sed -i`  it is creating some temporary files

When i use the above command for replace string
it is creating some temporary files like `sed6Y5vk6` with same original file size.

how can we avoid this.

Comment: [GNU SED](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) here it is mentioned as(@ -i option) `If no extension is supplied, the original file is overwritten without making a backup.`
 But am unable to get this.. can anyone help me out

Comment: try maybe `-u` `-unbuffered` option

Comment: @NeronLeVelu It is not working!!

Comment: Which sed version are you using? There is/was a known bug with the temporary files, see [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuwin32/bugs/534/) and [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuwin32/bugs/477/). Seems like the bug is still open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same bug over here, backup files are not deleted.
I'm back on sed 4.1.5 which works as expected for the time now.